# No compiler for language "Ada" when trying to compile for STM32

Tags: ada

I installed GNAT Community edition on Windows and I'm trying to write Ada code, compile it and flash it to STM32 Nucleo.
I started by compiling "hello world" project and compiler works fine, but when I opened an example project for STM32 from the AdaCore/Ada_Drivers_Library (Github) and tried to Build it I got the "No compiler for language "Ada" error.
The path to the compiler is in the envrironment variables.
In the GNAT Studio in Settings the "Compiler Path" and "Tools Path" have the same path, which is C:\GNAT\2020\bin and I checked the "Use the compiler in tools path to generate cross-reference files".

NOTE: in the installation proccess of AdaCore/Ada_Drivers_Library one installation step failed, it was the "python ./scripts/install_dependencies.py". I'm not sure if that's the problem.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: You did install the arm-elf cross-compiler?

Comment: No. I just did though, and that solves my problem, but it leads me to another one: "Could not locate executable on path: openocd". I have already C:\GNAT\2020-arm-elf\bin in system environments. I'm not sure how to overcome this problem now.

Comment: I don’t use Windows,  but on openocd.org they have likely installation packages

Comment: I'll research it. Thank you for your help!